# Comparing array variables in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have this script to compare two folders.

```
$firstfolder = Get-ChildItem C:\firstfolder
$secondfolder = Get-ChildItem C:\firstfolder

if ($firstfolder -eq $secondfolder) {
Write-Host "Folders are the same."
} else {
    Write-Host "Error: Doesn't match."
}
```

As you can see, I compare the same folder. Problem is, that it will never consider, that the arrays are equal. Why?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In PowerShell, variables that point to arrays are evaluated in expressions by enumerating the contents of the arrays themselves.

For example this expression:

```
$firstFolder | Get-Member
```

will return information about the [System.IO.DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) type, which indeed is the type of the *first* element in the `$firstFolder` array. If you want to operate on the array object itself, you have to explicitly tell PowerShell to treat the object as array by using the `,` operator. The following expression:

```
,$firstFolder | Get-Member
```

will expectedly return information about `System.Object[]`.

However, when the `-eq` operator is used between two array variables, things are a bit different. PowerShell will, in fact, enumerate only the array on the *left side* and compare each item to the array on the right side *as a whole*. The result will be **an array of matching items** or **nothing at all** when there are no matches. For example:

```
$a = 1..5
$b = 1..5
$a -eq $b         # returns zero-length array
[bool]($a -eq $b) # returns $false
$a -eq 3          # returns 3
```

In your particular case, the result will be zero-length array (or `$false` if casted to a [boolean](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.aspx)) since the `$firstFolder` array contains [System.IO.DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) objects that don't quite match the array in the `$secondFolder` variable.

What you really want is to compare the *contents* of both arrays against each other. This is where the [Compare-Object cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156812.aspx) comes in handy:

```
Compare-Object $firstFolder $secondFolder -SyncWindow 0
```

This will return an **array of differences** between the two arrays or `$null` when the arrays are equal. More precisely, the resulting array will contain an object for each item that exists only in one array and not the other. The `-SyncWindow 0` argument will make the order in which the items appear in the arrays count as a difference.

If all you need is a simple way to tell whether the two arrays are different without going into the details of *what* is different, you can simply check the length of the array returned by [Compare-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347568.aspx):

```
$areEqual = @(Compare-Object $firstFolder $secondFolder -SyncWindow 0).Length -eq 0
```

Notice how I explicitly told PowerShell to always package the results into an array, since [Compare-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347568.aspx) may return `$null` when the arrays don't contain any differences.

Comment: Thank you, Enrico. Did you mean, that it compares the names of the arrays instead of their content?

Comment: @culter The `-eq` operator actually compares the first object in each array. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for you exhausting answer, Enrico. It works perfectly. But as you wrote, the -eq operator compare first object of each array, why it returned false when I compared the same folder?

Comment: `$a -eq $b` return not nothing, but zero size array: `($a -eq $b).GetType().FullName; ($a -eq $b).Length`

Answer (score 6):

For this kind of comparisons you have to use cmdlet `compare-object` and evaluate if there's differences or not!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this (with the default -syncwindow, the order doesn't matter, but it's slower for large lists).

```
function arrayequal($a, $b) {
  -not (compare $a $b)
}

arrayequal $a $b

True
```

With matching order and faster:

```
function arrayequal($a, $b) {
  -not (compare $a $b -syncwindow 0)
}

arrayequal $a $b

True
```