# Scheduling Powershell changes ObjectType

Tags: powershell, scripting, automation, powershell-2.0

I've written a little script that checks for differences between 2 text files.

```
    $new = get-content $outPutFile
    $old = get-content $outPutFileYesterday
    $result = $null
    $result = Compare-Object $old $new

    $resultHTML =  $result.GetEnumerator() | ConvertTo-Html
    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer 10.14.23.4 -From me@mail.com -To $toAddress -Subject "DiffTest" -Body "$resultHTML" -BodyAsHtml
```

When I run it from an active PowerShell prompt, all is well. However, when I try to schedule it to run daily I get this error on the run-time (the block above is in a try catch that mails any execution errors):

> Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] doesn't contain a method named 'GetEnumerator'.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script may run in a **different user context** when scheduled, potentially with a **different set of read/write permissions** on the filesystem.

However, In PowerShell [arrays are automatically enumerated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9598371/26396) when used in expressions, so you don't need to 
call the `GetEnumerator()` method before passing it to [ConvertTo-Html](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347572.aspx).

You could start by changing your script to:

```
$resultHTML =  $result | ConvertTo-Html
```

and see how it impacts the result.

Answer (score 2):

`Compare-Object` either returns:

- `$null`: if the ReferenceObject and the DifferenceObject are equal
- an object of type `PSCustomObject`: if only one item differs **(1)**
- an array of objects: if multiple differences have been found

Of these return values only the last one (the array) has a `GetEnumerator()` method. `ConvertTo-Html` produces the expected output when fed either of these return values, so you can safely drop the `.GetEnumerator()` part (as mentioned by Enrico). Another option is to wrap the `$result` in an array, which would change line 6 of your script to:

`$resultHTML =  @($result).GetEnumerator() | ConvertTo-Html`

**(1) This is the return value for compare-object in your script**