# Is powershell assigning lazy?

Tags: powershell

I have the following code

```
$a = ls
....
$a | ? { ... }
```

Will `$a` be assigned when the first line is executed? Or it will not execute until it hits `$a | ? { ... }`?

Why the following code not return true?

```
$b = @(1,2);
$c = $b;
$b -eq $c
```

Comment: These are really separate (non-related) questions, and as such should be posted separately. Just keep in mind for the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question:

`$a` is assigned when the first line is executed

try:

```
$a = ls

$a.gettype(); # now $a is an array of [fileinfo] and/or [directoryinfo]
```

Second question:

read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598173/comparing-array-variables-in-powershell)

and note:

```
$b.Equals($c)
```

return `true`