# Behaviour of PowerShell's -eq vs compare-object

Tags: powershell, operators, compareobject

Why does Compare-Object work as expected where -EQ fails to accurately compare arrays of strings?

I had a PowerShell script which was populating an array of strings and was using the -EQ operator to test against the expected values - this was always failing - I think the following code illustrates the issues

```
    # Setting up 4 Lists - $Lists1 2 and 3 should be identical and $List4 differs
    [string[]]$List1  = "AA","BBB"
              $List2  = $List1

    [string[]]$List3  = "AA"
              $List3 += "BBB"

    [string[]]$List4  = $List3
              $List4 += "CCCC"

    "--------"
    "Checking for Equality of the Lists using the -EQ comparison operator (why do all fail--- when only List4 should fail)"
    "--------"
    if ($List1 -eq $List1) {"List 1 and 1 are equal"} else {"List 1 and 1 are NOT equal"}
    if ($List1 -eq $List2) {"List 1 and 2 are equal"} else {"List 1 and 2 are NOT equal"}
    if ($List1 -eq $List3) {"List 1 and 3 are equal"} else {"List 1 and 3 are NOT equal"}
    if ($List1 -eq $List4) {"List 1 and 4 are equal"} else {"List 1 and 4 are NOT equal"}
    ""
    ""
    "--------"
    "Checking using Compare-object (operates as expected - only List4 Differs)"
    "--------"
    if ((compare-object $List1 $List1) -eq $null) {"List 1 and 1 are equal"} else {"List 1 and 1 are NOT equal"}
    if ((compare-object $List1 $List2) -eq $null) {"List 1 and 2 are equal"} else {"List 1 and 2 are NOT equal"}
    if ((compare-object $List1 $List3) -eq $null) {"List 1 and 3 are equal"} else {"List 1 and 3 are NOT equal"}
    if ((compare-object $List1 $List4) -eq $null) {"List 1 and 4 are equal"} else {"List 1 and 4 are NOT equal"}
```

Comment: `$List1 -eq $List1` doesn't return anything, I assume `-eq` doesn't work for arrays.

Comment: You should read how comparison operators (including `-eq`) work when left hand side operand is collection. Also, `Compare-Object` does not compare lists, it compare content of lists.

Comment: @4c74356b41 It return zero size array, not nothing.

Comment: Is there another operator that can be used to compare the Array - or do I have to use the compare-object cmdlet ?  are there inefficiencies in using the cmdlet?

Comment: Thank you James C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598173/comparing-array-variables-in-powershell) - which is certainly worth reading as it very elequently explains your question:

---

When the `-eq` operator is used between two array variables, things are a bit different. PowerShell will, in fact, enumerate only the array on the *left side* and compare each item to the array on the right side *as a whole*. The result will be **an array of matching items** or **nothing at all** when there are no matches.

`Compare-Object` will return an **array of differences** between the two arrays or `$null` when the arrays are equal. More precisely, the resulting array will contain an object for each item that exists only in one array and not the other.

Comment: I think I have it now - thanks. In summary THE -EQ operator only returns a status of TRUE when There is only one element in the 2nd operand - and .... - and - ANY element in the first operand has to match THE SINGLE ELEMENT in the 2nd operand. So if List1= A, B and List2=A then List1 -eq List2 returns TRUE. if List1= A and List2=A, B then List1 -eq List2 returns FALSE

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain it to you with an **example**:

```
$a1 = @(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
$b1 = @(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
$c = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (1..5) -DifferenceObject (1..6) -PassThru
```

***`$c` will be 6.***

That's what compare object does

Where -EQ only checks like if the left-hand side is equal to the right or not. It results in a boolean value.

**Example**

```
$DNS = (Test-Connection www.google.com -quiet)
If($DNS -eq "True") {Write-Host "The Internet is available"}
ElseIf($DNS -ne "True") {Restart-Service dnscache}
```

Comment: Thanks Ranadip - My problem - and the reason for this query is that  I thought EQ worked like you stated and expected that EQ would check if the left-hand equals the right hand operand - 
but that does not seem to work as expected for arrays.  

for example ... try this 
   [string[]]$List1="A","B" 
   [string[]]$List2="A","B"  
   if ($List1 -eq $List1) {"List1 ---$List1--- Equals itself"} else {"List1 ---$List1---  DOES NOT Equal itself"}
   if ($List1 -eq $List2) {"List1 ---$List1--- and 2 ---$List2--- are equal"} else {"List1 ---$List1--- and 2 ---$List2--- are NOT equal"}`

Comment: Yes.. I second you.. eq has some limitations also.

Comment: But if you do remove one element from the list. Then it will take. The reason being you are converting an array to string as a Type Cast and EQ cannot handle that. Try this. It will work . 
`[string[]]$List1="A" 
[string[]]$List2="A" 
if ($List1 -eq $List1) {"List1 ---$List1--- Equals itself"} 
else {"List1 ---$List1--- DOES NOT Equal itself"} 

if ($List1 -eq $List2) {"List1 ---$List1--- and 2 ---$List2--- are equal"} 
else {"List1 ---$List1--- and 2 ---$List2--- are NOT equal"}`