# Set-Content and then Get-Content change the content somehow

Tags: powershell

PowerShell changes the contents of a text file on `Get-Content` or the variable on `Set-Content`.

This is a PowerShell script for compiling a bunch of files and formatting them to a single text file, this part checks if the new file is equal to the old one, but according to the comparison, it never is. I've tried messing with stuff like making the new var be a string array as get-content is.

```cs
$files = Get-ChildItem -path "./dir" | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Name -match '[A-J]'}

$var = @()
foreach ($file in $files){
    $filePath = "dir\" + $file;
    $fileContent = Get-Content $filepath
    $var += $fileContent
}
$firstLine = '"this" "issen" "da" "first"'
$var1 = '"abc" "def" "12" "6"'
$var2 = '"456" "def" "12" "4"'
$newContent = $firstLine,$var,$var1,$var2
$oldContent = Get-Content './File.txt'

if (-not (Compare-Object $oldContent $newContent)) {
    Write-Host Nothing new.
} else {
    Write-Host Something new
    Set-Content './File.txt' -value $newContent
}
Set-Content './File.txt' -value $newContent
pause
```

When comparing `$newContent` to `$oldContent` which is just `$newContent` stored and retrieved from a text file they are not identical. They should be, right?

The text files that are gathered from ./dir are like this:
a00.txt

```
a12 bc23 abc
```

b00.txt

```
a12 bc23 abg
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `-eq` to compare array. Try using `Compare-object`. For more information about comparing array take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598173/comparing-array-variables-in-powershell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first line `$var = "stuff","and","thangs"` creates an array (3 strings):

[image]

The `-eq` operator doesn't work like that for comparing **object arrays**. You can instead use the **[Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object?view=powershell-6)** cmdlet:

```
if (-not (Compare-Object $var $var2)) {
 Write-Host True
}
```

---

**Answer to your edit:**

Your first variable (`$newContent`) is an array of strings but also includes **another array of strings**. See here:

```
PS D:\temp> $newContent -join ''
"this" "issen" "da" "first"System.Object[]"abc" "def" "12" "6""456" "def" "12" "4"

PS D:\temp> $oldContent -join ''
"this" "issen" "da" "first"a12 bc23 abca12 bc23 abg"abc" "def" "12" "6""456" "def" "12" "4"
```

A ***workaround*** is to pipe the variable to the `Out-String` cmdlet, but you might find a cleaner way to solve it ;-)

```
Compare-Object ($oldContent | out-string) ($newContent | out-string)
```

Comment: To elaborate a little more, the reason for this behavior is that the `-eq` operator compares the *identity* of the two array objects and will only return "true" if both variables contain a reference to the exact same object, whereas references to different objects will return "false" even if both objects contain the same elements.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar, that explains why it doesn't return true.

Comment: This works for the example, but not my actual script and data set

Comment: I've no clue why. The actual data set is on multiple lines, can that affect it? I get it with a ```foreach ($file in $files){ $var += $fileContent } ```

Comment: @Jokru Yes, that is a difference because using $var += you *concat* a string whereas the Get-Content cmdlet returns a string array (if you don't use the `-raw` switch)

Comment: @MartinBrandl even if I initiated the string as ```$var = @()``` ?

Comment: @Jokru Probably yes. Please consider creating a reproducible example, mentioned by Ansgar

Comment: @Jokru Sorry, but you didn't provide a verifiable example. There are also variables like $firstline, $var1 and $var2 which are not declared.

Comment: Please provide a script which we can copy paste & run that shows the actual issue you have

Comment: @MartinBrandl you'll have to copy and paste the files as well

Comment: Thank you, my next idea was to just write to a temp file, which would've been messier.