# Is -and comparison evaluated individually or against the same object?

Tags: powershell, powershell-6.0

I am looking for missing events between two arrays: `$tc_records` & `$RelationshipEvents_array`. Both arrays should have the same two entries.

An entry for A->B and reverse B->A. When I'm evaluating RelationshipEvents with -and statement, does one (same) event gets evaluated, or each side of the -and loads the array and evaluates is independently.

```
foreach ($record in $tc_records) {
    # is this using the same RelationshipEvent for both comparisons or two different comparisons?
    if($RelationshipEvents_array.entity1Id -eq $record.entity1Id -and $RelationshipEvents_array.entity2Id -eq $record.entity2Id){
        $re_tc_matched_record.Add($record)
    } else {
        $re_tc_not_matched_record.Add($record)
    }    
}
```

```
in case this makes any difference:
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      6.2.3
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    6.2.3
OS                             Darwin 19.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.0.0: Thu Oct 17 16:17:15 PDT 2019; root:xnu-6153.41.3~29/RELEASE_X86_64
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your two arrays hold similar objects with various properties. 
When you perform this:

```
foreach ($record in $tc_records) {
    if($RelationshipEvents_array.entity1Id -eq $record.entity1Id -and $RelationshipEvents_array.entity2Id -eq $record.entity2Id)
...
```

You're actually comparing an array holding all the `entity1Id` properties (calculated by getting the property of that name from each of the objects in the `$RelationshipEvents_array` array) with the `entity1Id` property of the current `$record` object.

This is unlikely to ever evaluate to true given the different object types unless I've misunderstood your question.

What I would normally do when making a comparison like this is something like the following to get a match:

```
if($RelationshipEvents_array.entity1Id -contains $record.entity1Id)
...
```

However, since you're trying to match two properties the simplest way might be to:

Iterate through the array for each record you check in a second foreach loop

```
foreach ($record in $tc_records) {
    foreach ($event in $RelationshipEvents_array) {
        if ($record.entity1Id -eq $event.entity1Id -and $record.entity2Id -eq $event.entity2Id)
{ # Do matchy stuff
...
```

Comment: That's what I was wondering. If I was performing two independent calculations against separate collections. Problem is, in my scenario they DO evaluate to true

Comment: I had a similar nested loop, but with a nested `if`.. gonna try your approach, hopefully get rid of the nested if.

Comment: I realized that because I'm looking for missing events, if I do nested loop, I can get partial match on the first property, and will never find values where partial match is on the 2nd property. So I have to do it by testing both properties at the same time.

Comment: Sorry can you clarify where you're doing partial matches? I'm not sure I understand. I was going to add another way to check both properties at the same time using indices and a for loop but it was a bit convoluted so I avoided it but if that's truly necessary it might be the way to go.

Comment: I'll try :) So, we get messages, and each message has a pair, and the two messages are mapped to each other: Message1 id1 -> message2 id2 & message 2 id1 -> message 1 id2. With me so far? Now all of these messages are picked off by another system and duplicated. So a pair in system 1 and a pair in system 2. My goal is to find missing messages in the two pairs, across 2 systems. Is the main sender dropping messages, or the duplication process between two systems, (or perhaps even our logging system just not reporting all results)

Answer (score 0):

You do have the compare object cmdlet to do array comparisons for you with quite a few options to output non-matching objects between the arrays.

```
$a1=@(1,2,3,4,5)
$b1=@(1,2,3,4,5,6)

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a1 -DifferenceObject $b1
```

To answer your question though, -and is a just evaluating a separate 2nd function that must also equal `true` for the statement to be evaluated.

```
if (true){#runs}
if (false){#no runs}
if (true -and true){#runs}
if (true -and false){#no runs}
if (false -and true){#no runs}
```

You seem to be using `-eq` on a separate array, hard to tell exactly with no example data but you should be able to test your logic by simply doing `$RelationshipEvents_array.entity1Id -eq $record.entity1Id` and checking if it returns true or false as you are expecting it would. If `$RelationshipEvents_array` is an array you probably want to use `-contains`

Comment: it's a complex object with multiple properties, afaik compare object only works on strings.

Comment: My example of the cmdlet shows it working on ints and powershells own examples of the cmdlet show how to use it on multi-property objects such as ones returned by `get-process`. Regardless, does the 2nd half of my answer help? If you have a close look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9598371/5487553) you will see that using `-eq` on an array doesn't return true or false but rather array of results that matched.

Comment: I'll take a look again. Simple examples come back as expected, but when I load full collection 1000s of objects, some results come back as false positives. So i'm not sure what's causing it. All of the objects are normalized

Comment: This approach wont work. This example only works with single value strings, every if object has many values, PS examples evaluate only one property. That's easy :)