# How to compare this objects?

Tags: powershell

I have a logic here that I want to use on my script. I What would be the best way to compare this 2 objects?

```
C:\Users\***> $value1

My Name 1
My Name 1

C:\Users\***> $Value2

My Name 1
My Name 1

C:\Users\***> if($value1 -eq $value2){ Write-Host "True"} else {Write-Host "False"}
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
This is my function that I want to use for the logic. I keep getting false return with my if statement

```
$NestedGroupUsers = Get-ADUsers_cachedV2 -GroupName $nestedmember.distinguishedName
          
    $table2 = $NestedGroupUsers | Add-Member -NotePropertyName MainParentGroup -NotePropertyValue $groupNestedName -PassThru  -Force 
    
    $AddedMainGroupTable = MainGroupChoice -InputObject $table2 -choice1 $adgroupname.name -Choice2 $groupNestedName -Value1  $table2.MainParentGroup -Value2 $table2.ParentGroup 
    
    function MainGroupChoice {
        param (
            [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]$InputObject,
            [Parameter(ValuefromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)] $Value1,
            [Parameter(ValuefromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)] $Value2,
            [Parameter(ValuefromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)][String] $Choice1,
            [Parameter(ValuefromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)][String] $Choice2
        )    
    
        process {
            # value1 = table2.parentGroup ,
            # value2 = table2.parentGroup 
            # choice1 = adgroupname, 
            #choice2 nestedmember,distinguishedname 
        
            if ($Value1 -eq $Value2 ) {
                return $InputObject |Add-Member -NotePropertyName MainGroup -NotePropertyValue $choice1 -PassThru  -Force
            }
            else {
                return $InputObject |Add-Member -NotePropertyName MainGroup -NotePropertyValue $Choice2  -PassThru  -Force
            }
        }
    
    }
```

Why am I getting False with these?
I want to implement it here. Data is from object. I keep getting to false

Comment: You should show how the values are being populated. Your post does not clearly show what the data-types of `$value1` and `$value2` are, or whether it is possible that one of the variables has trailing whitespace at the end of a line.

Comment: Data is from my function object. I sent an answer for my reference.

Comment: See here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598173/comparing-array-variables-in-powershell#answer-9598371

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting false because you have declared the $Value2 variable and in the if section you are refering to the $value2 variable which does not exist. Just change `if($value1 -eq $Value2){ Write-Host "True"} else {Write-Host "False"}` and you should get a return True. Or just change $Value2 to $value2 when you declare them again.