# Powershell array turns into hashtable when assigning it to a hashtable

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

In powershell I have this code:

```
$AddTags = @()
$AddTags = $AddTags + "ABC"
$AddTags = $AddTags + "abc"
$Object = @{
    "id"   = 1;
    "tags" = $AddTags
}
if($Object.tags -ne $AddTags)
{
    "Why is this?"
}
```

For some reason, $Object.tags doesn't equal $AddTags. Why i hover over $Object in VS code debug mode, I can see that $Object.tags contains a hashtable with one Entry, being the key "tags" and the value $AddTags. Why is that?

I have searched for this Problem and haven't found it anywhere.

Comment: .tags is not a Hashtable. `$Object.tags.GetType()` --> System.Array. Use `Compare-Object` to test if arrays have the same elements

Comment: If you are trying to add to that fixed array, you'd use `+=`; which isn't recommended to begin with. So, it would be: `$AddTags += 'ABC'; $AddTags += 'abc'`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Theo. The problem here is that I didn't compare the arrays correctly. I learned how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598173/comparing-array-variables-in-powershell). Modifying the code like this works:

```
$AddTags = @()
$AddTags = $AddTags + "ABC"
$AddTags = $AddTags + "abc"
$Object = @{
    "id"   = 1;
    "tags" = $AddTags
}
$areEqual = @(Compare-Object $Object.tags $AddTags).Length -eq 0
if(!$areEqual)
{
    "This will no longer show up."
}
```